# Defining covectors when the basis is oblique

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensors

Given a $2$-dimensional vector space with an oblique unit length basis, say, $(f_1, f_2)$, what is the dual vector or covector corresponding to $f_1$, call it $\hat f_1$?

There appear to me to be two possible definitions, with $v=(a, b)_f$, written in the given basis.

- Definition 1: $\hat f_1 :(a, b)_f \mapsto a$
- Definition 2: $\hat f_1 :(a, b)_f \mapsto \textrm{(the projection of the vector $(a, b)_f$ on $(1, 0)_f$)}.$

I note that definiton 2 seems to require a metric, but that can be inferred from the usual dot product in an orthonormal basis.

I have seen both definitions.  For orthogonal bases they are the same, but not for oblique bases.

Which is it?

Comment: In definition $2$, I suppose you mean (scalar) *orthogonal* projection.

Comment: Yes, orthogonal projection.

Comment: Using defnition 1, when you have a basis change from the cartesian basis e1 e2 to the oblique basis, the covector e1hat doesn't transform to f1hat, which is hanging me up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the first definition: Given a basis $\mathcal F = (f_i)$ of a finite-dimensional vector space $\Bbb V$, the *dual basis* of the dual space, $\Bbb V^*$, is the unique basis $(\hat f{}^i)$  of $\Bbb V^*$ such that $$\hat f{}^i(f_j) = \left\{\begin{array}{rl}1,& i = j \\ 0,& i \neq j\end{array}\right.$$
In particular, if $v = \pmatrix{a\\b}_{\mathcal F}$, so that $v = a f_1 + b f_2$, then $$\hat f{}^1(v) = \hat f{}^1(a f_1 + b f_2) = a \hat f{}^1(f_1) + b \hat f{}^1(f_2) = a (1) + b(0) = a .$$
Like you observe, this definition does not require an inner product.

Note that the two definitions coincide in the case that the given basis $\mathcal F$ is orthogonal with respect to the inner product used.

Comment: OK, but suppose f1 = (1, 0)e (e for cartesian), and f2 = (.7 .7)e, then e1hat doesn't transform to f1hat.   For example (0, 1)e = (-1, 1.4)f, and e1hat(0,1)e = 0 while f1hat(-1, 1.4) = -1 ?????

Comment: Do you mean, how do you write the first basis element $\hat f{}^1$ of the basis dual to $(f_1, f_2)$ in terms of the basis $(\hat e{}^1, \hat e{}^2)$ dual to $(e_1, e_2)$?

Comment: The direct tranform matrix from the ehat basis to the fhat basis is [1 0; -1 1.4] .... :) ... I've been working on this for 2 days !   Note: but I'm using slightly off-standard notation as I'm doing all transfoms as matrix * vector.  So f1hat = e1hat.

Comment: Son of a gun, I was missing a transpose, direct transform fro ehat basis to fhat is [1 -1; 0 1.4] in my notational  variation, so (0,1)e = (-1,1.4)f and f1hat = e1hat - e2hat, and f1hat:(-1, 1.4)f = e1hat;(0,1)e - e2hat:(0,1)e.  Thanks.  I upvoted your answer but it didn't register.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, you can also "accept" it (instead of or in addition to upvoting it). NB you can upvote as many answers to your question as you'd like, but you can only accept one.

Comment: (And you're welcome, I hope you found it useful.)